# How to get Url without uri paramters in Middleware - AspCore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-middleware

I was implementing a custom middleware and I was trying to access the request url without the Uri parameters.

All what I have access while implementing a custom middleware is `HttpContext`

```cs
    public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
```

The `HttpContext` has a property `Request` that has a `Path` property which could return back the full url with URI parameters.

For example: `/api/v1/customer/12345` What I want to get is the route `api/v1/customer/{customerId}`

Is this something fesiable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this something fesiable?

No,you can't.A route is an ASP.NET Core MVC concept and its existence can therefore only be found within the MVC middleware of ASP.NET Core.

Not sure what is your middleware used to do.As a workaround is that you could did your stuff in Action Filter:

```
public class LogActionFilter : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context)
    {

    }

    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        //get the request route template
        var routeTemplate = context.ActionDescriptor.AttributeRouteInfo.Template;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm late, but I had to do it in a middleware and did this with following function:

```cs
    private string GetRoutePath(HttpContext httpContext)
    {
        string path = httpContext.Request.Path.ToString();
        string[] pathValues = path.Split("/");
        RouteData route = httpContext.GetRouteData();

        // Remove controller and action values from route.
        // We are looking to replace parameters only
        route.Values.Remove("controller");
        route.Values.Remove("action");
        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object?> routeValue in route.Values)
        {
            for (int i=1; i< pathValues.Length; i++)
            {
                if (routeValue.Value == null) { continue; }
                
                if (pathValues[i].Equals(routeValue.Value.ToString(), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                {
                    pathValues[i] = "{" + routeValue.Key + "}";
                }
            }
        }

        return string.Join("/", pathValues);
    }
```